# GreenDao whereOr and conditions adding in a loop

Tags: java, android, greendao

I need to add some `or` clauses to query. I need to do it in a loop.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(symptoms, ",");
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
     qb.whereOr(Properties.Symptom.like("%" + st.nextToken() + "%"));
}
```

How I can add those `or` conditions properly, because this above is not working as expected. I want to add `or` for every symptom.

Answer (score 4):

[If you look at the documentation](http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao/de/greenrobot/dao/QueryBuilder.html#whereOr%28de.greenrobot.dao.WhereCondition,%20de.greenrobot.dao.WhereCondition,%20de.greenrobot.dao.WhereCondition...%29), you'll see that `whereOr()` takes an unbounded number of conditions. What you want to do is add them all at once in an array:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(symptoms, ",");

ArrayList<WhereCondition> whereConditions = new ArrayList<WhereCondition>();

while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
     whereConditions.add(Properties.Symptom.like("%" + st.nextToken() + "%"));
}

// Give the ArrayList an already allocated array to place its contents in.
WhereCondition[] conditionsArray = new WhereCondition[whereConditions.size()];
conditionsArray = whereConditions.toArray(conditionsArray);

qb.whereOr(conditionsArray);
```

It looks like the method call in the documentation takes two non-array WhereConditions and then an ellipsized argument, which accepts an array or an additional comma-separated list of objects. So you might have to do something like this to get it to work properly:

```
qb.whereOr(conditionsArray[0], conditionsArray[1], Arrays.copyOfRange(conditionsArray, 2, conditionsArray.length));
```

ADDENDUM: It looks like you're using APIs that don't match the documentation, possibly an older version of greenDAO. I wrote this solution based off the current documentation. I can't  guarantee that it will work for you. I recommend updating if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(symptoms, ",");
WhereCondition where = null;
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    if (where != null) {
        where = qb.or(where, Properties.Symptom.like("%" + st.nextToken() + "%"));
    } else {
        where = Properties.Symptom.like("%" + st.nextToken() + "%");
    }
}
qb.where(where).list();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I added my own method in an Util class to perform the same behavior when I have one or several WhereCondition in an array.

Here is my gateway method :

```
public static QueryBuilder whereOr(QueryBuilder queryBuilder, WhereCondition[] whereConditions){
        if(whereConditions == null) return queryBuilder.where(null);
        else if(whereConditions.length == 1) return queryBuilder.where(whereConditions[0]);
        else return queryBuilder.whereOr(whereConditions[0], whereConditions[1], Arrays.copyOfRange(whereConditions, 2, whereConditions.length));
    }
```

Use : `Util.whereOr(queryBuilder, whereConditionsArray);`

Default : Can't use the Builder Pattern from the QueryBuilder with this approach

(More later) Here, I share you some code which could spare you time when developping DAO methods.

```
public class QueryBuilderUtil {
    public static final String EQ = "=?";
    public static final String NOTEQ = "<>?";
    public static final String LIKE = " LIKE ?";
    public static final String GE = ">=?";
    public static final String LE = "<=?";
    public static final String GT = ">?";
    public static final String LT = "<?";


    public static QueryBuilder whereOrOnSamePropertyWithDifferentValues(QueryBuilder queryBuilder, Property property, String operation, String values, String separator) {
        return whereOrOnSamePropertyWithDifferentValues(queryBuilder, property, operation, values.split(separator));

    }

    public static QueryBuilder whereOrOnSamePropertyWithDifferentValues(QueryBuilder queryBuilder, Property property, String operation, String[] values) {
        WhereCondition[] whereConditions = new WhereCondition[values.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (String value : values) {
            whereConditions[i++] = new WhereCondition.PropertyCondition(property, operation, value);
        }
        return whereOr(queryBuilder, whereConditions);
    }

    public static QueryBuilder whereOr(QueryBuilder queryBuilder, WhereCondition[] whereConditions) {
        if (whereConditions == null) return queryBuilder.where(null);
        else if (whereConditions.length == 1) return queryBuilder.where(whereConditions[0]);
        else return queryBuilder.whereOr(whereConditions[0], whereConditions[1], Arrays.copyOfRange(whereConditions, 2, whereConditions.length));
    }
}
```

With this class, you can perform a whereOr with the same property on multiples "values string" in one line. It was necessary to clean my code :). However you can only do simple operations like variables declared in the class.

Example :

```
public List<Block> loadAllByModId(String mods_id) {
        synchronized (this) {
            QueryBuilder<Block> queryBuilder = queryBuilder();
            QueryBuilderUtil.whereOrOnSamePropertyWithDifferentValues(queryBuilder, Properties.ModId, QueryBuilderUtil.EQ, mods_id, ";");
            query_list = queryBuilder.build();
        }
        Query<Block> query = query_list.forCurrentThread();
        return query.list();
    }
```

Hope it helps